# Guardar "url de descarga" obtenida de Firebase en una Base de Datos

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, url

Tengo una app que permite seleccionar imágenes del celular y guardarlas en Firebase y asi guardar la "url de descarga" en la base de datos... El problema es que al guardar la URL en la base de datos solo me guarda la mitad de esta url.
Hice un toast para verificar si capturaba toda la URL y si lo hacia..
-Uso webservice
-El tipo de dato que uso en la DB es LONGTEXT
¿Cuál podría ser mi error?

```js
//obtener url de descarga de la imagen de firebase
Uri DescargarFoto = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
//Mostrar imagen en una ImageView
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
  .load(DescargarFoto)
  .fitCenter()
  .centerCrop()
  .into(Imagenview);
//Mostrar url de la imagen
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "url de la imagen: " + DescargarFoto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

```js
@Override
public void run() {
  //guardar "url de descarga" en la base de datos
  enviarDatosGET(DescargarFoto);
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos almacenados con Exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: "El tipo de dato que uso en la DB es LONGTEXT" , ¿ la base de datos es Firebase ???

Comment: se carga una sola imagen o varias imágenes a la vez? dependiendo de eso es la recomendación. como estas guardando la url?

Comment: Gracias por comentar! ya encontré la solución yo mismo revisando mi código por horas... la url tenia un carácter especial ("&"), es por eso que solo me guardaba la mitad de la url, lo arregle guardando la url de esta forma:

`URLEncoder.encode(DescargarFoto.toString(),"UTF-8")`

Comment: @AndyPuertasAlejos me podrías ayudar dándome un ejemplo? tengo el mismo problema, quiero guardar la url de la imagen para poder mostrar esta imagen siempre sin necesidad de cargarla cada vez que lo necesite y no encuentro la solución todavía... Ojalá puedas ayudarme. Saludos y gracias desde ya!